# Filter objects in an array based on regex applied to property

Tags: javascript

I have this data structure:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "first item",
    T1_something: 21,
    T1_anotherthing: 15,
    T1_hello: 98,
    T2_coding: 12.3,
    T2_world: 4.1,
    T2_different: 2.5
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "second item",
    T1_something: 3,
    T1_anotherthing: 12.6,
    T1_hello: 64.1,
    T2_coding: 71.3,
    T2_world: 4.5,
    T2_different: 3.3
  }
];
```

I want to get only properties where the property name matches the following regex `/^T\d/`

So my desired output is this:

```
const desiredResult = [
  {
    T1_something: 21,
    T1_anotherthing: 15,
    T1_hello: 98,
    T2_coding: 12.3,
    T2_world: 4.1,
    T2_different: 2.5
  },
  {
    T1_something: 3,
    T1_anotherthing: 12.6,
    T1_hello: 64.1,
    T2_coding: 71.3,
    T2_world: 4.5,
    T2_different: 3.3
  }
];
```

How do I go about doing this filtering based on a regex in an array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution

```
const desiredResult = data.map(o=>{
    const newO={};
    Object.keys(o).filter(oKey=>/^T\d/.test(oKey)).forEach(oKey=>{
        newO[oKey]=o[oKey]
    })

    return newO;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "first item",
    T1_something: 21,
    T1_anotherthing: 15,
    T1_hello: 98,
    T2_coding: 12.3,
    T2_world: 4.1,
    T2_different: 2.5
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "second item",
    T1_something: 3,
    T1_anotherthing: 12.6,
    T1_hello: 64.1,
    T2_coding: 71.3,
    T2_world: 4.5,
    T2_different: 3.3
  }
];

const filterBasedOnProp = (elements, pattern) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(pattern)
  
  return elements.map((element) => Object.keys(element).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    if (key.match(regex)) accumulator[key] = element[key]
    
    return accumulator
  }, {}))
}

console.log(filterBasedOnProp(data, "^T"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// const data = ...
// const regexp = ...

function filterMyDataProperties(data, regexp) {
  return data.map(item => {
    return Object.keys(item).reduce((newItem, key) => {
      if (regexp.test(key)) {
        newItem[key] = item[key]
      }
  
      return newItem
    }, {})
  })
}

const result = filterMyDataProperties(data, regexp);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).